# FFT of sinosidal signal- posetive and negetive frequency

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to work with FFT in python but I am faced with a strange problem regarding negative and positive frequency

I would like to use fft (scipy.fftpack) to find the magnitude and phase of the main harmonic of my signal. My signal is close to the Sinusial signal with some noise nad frequency close 50 Hz. Now when I use FFT, it gives me two main components?!

Let's look at a simple case, getting FFT from a Sinosidal signa.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tt = np.arange(0,0.02,50e-6)
xx= np.sin(2*np.pi*50*tt)

XX = fft(xx)
ff = np.arange(400)/400/50e-6

plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
plt.subplot(121)

plt.plot(ff,np.abs(XX))
plt.xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('FFT Amplitude |v_ins_f_a(freq)|')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(tt, 2*ifft(XX), 'r-')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of the code (FFT)]

As we can see here, the FFT shows an output on 50 Hz as expected and another one in -50 (or 20000 as labled in the Fig) Hz.

However, I want to have just one posetive frequency in FFT! what should I do? If I just chose the value related to 50 HZ and do ifft, the signal will not be the original!

Any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just take the positive frequency if you want your time domain signal to be strictly real (not imaginary or complex).  That's just the way the math works, like 1+1=2.

You need to feed an IFFT a complex conjugate symmetric signal (thus including matching negative frequency data) if you want your result to be strictly real.  Or use an RFFT, which does that for you under the hood.